# express: command not found after installing express-generator@4.15.5

Tags: node.js

My first post here, after reading hours and solving many problems for me:)

Im running macbook OS X El Captain.

1. I installed Node v8.9.4
2. I run "sudo npm install -g  express-generator" I get the following feedback:

myname-MacBook-Air:todo myname$ sudo npm install -g  express-generator
/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/express -> /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js
+ express-generator@4.15.5
updated 1 package in 1.052s

3. When I now try to run "express newproject", I get the following error:

myname-MacBook-Air:todo myname$ express newproject
-bash: express: command not found

I have a feeling I might have some paths set up the wrong way. I appreciate help!

Answer (score 1):

The executable is installed in

```
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/
```

Try add that directory to your path and it will solve the problem.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for replay! I`ve run "export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH" in terminal. I still get "-bash: express: command not found" when I run "express" command.  When I run "npm run express <name>" I get "npm ERR! missing script: express"

Comment: try run again : sudo npm install -g express-generator@latest

Comment: /Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/express -> /Users/myname/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js
+ express-generator@4.15.5
updated 1 package in 0.988s

That is the same version as the previous and does not help. :)

Comment: Global package are installed in : /usr/local/lib/node_modules however your path here is : /Users/myname/.npm-global/bin/express

Comment: try : export PATH=/Users/myname/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

Comment: This has been annoying me for maybe 8-10 hours... You just made my day! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to have been able to help you:)

Answer (score 1):

Install Express Globally

```
1] npm install express -g
```

and also install express-generator locally, If it is not working then try to do that by globally

`2] npm install express-generator` or `npm install express-generator -g`